# How to load external config file in Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, es6-modules

I am using Docker to build a Node app image. I am having my configurations in a YAML file which is located at `source_folder/config.yaml`.

When doing `await readFile(new URL('../config.yaml', import.meta.url), 'utf8')` in my `index` file it says file not found after running. However, doing - `COPY config.yaml ./` in `Dockerfile` solves it but I don't want to copy my credentials in the image build.

Is there any solution I can load the config file after building the image?

Using ESM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [`dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) to load my env variables. I understand the need to not include it in builds. Docker provides a runtime solution of including these variables to your env by passing the file as an argument. So this is what I do to load my env while using `docker run`:

```sh
docker run -e VARIABLE_NAME=variable_value image_to_be_executed

# or 

docker run --env-file path_to_env_file image_to_be_executed
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this and then class to parse the variable into objects.